# Change configuration of a single project in the solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am creating a .sln using cmake which consists of multiple projects. All the projects except one have to be of x64 platform except one, which is supposed to be of Win32 platform. I choose

> "Visual Studio 10 Win64"

while running the top level cmakelist.txt. 
Also I have used

> set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Visual Studio 10" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

in the project which I need to have Win32. But I get this error when I reconfigure using the same CmakeCache.

> CMake Error: Error: generator : Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64. Does not match the generator used previously: Visual Studio 10

How do I change the platform for just one project in a multilevel CMake project?

Comment: Try without `CACHE`?

Comment: I used  ExternalProject_Add(), and specified CMAKE_GENERATOR as "Visual Studio 10" and it worked.